# Config Transforms and CruiseControl.net

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

How is it possible to Transform configuration from a CruiseControl.net build?

I have the following in my CC project (snipped for brevity):

```
   <msbuild>
    <executable>C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe</executable>
    <buildArgs>/noconsolelogger /P:TransformConfigFiles=true /p:Configuration=Development /v:diag</buildArgs>
  </msbuild>
```

Where “Development” is the name of the configuration build. Is “TransformConfigFiles” actually the correct command line argument?

The CC project executes without error, it’s just that actual transform doesn’t happen. It’s meant to replace the connection string. Here’s the transform config:

Web.Development.config using "set attributes" transform:

```
<add name="DbConnectionNameHere" connectionString="myConnectionHere" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen that (/P) parameter (TransformConfigFiles).  That doesn't mean I'm omniscient.

Check this one out:

[web.config file transform from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10506308/web-config-file-transform-from-command-line)

I think the below substantiates my guess about "TransformConfigFiles":

[TFS 2012 and web.config transforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16311981/tfs-2012-and-web-config-transforms/18122871#18122871)