# wpp.target could not write destination file in TFS Auto Build

Tags: c#, tfs, msbuild

I'm having a problem trying to get my builds to work on TFS.  I have a user called TFSBuild and it has access to the C:\Builds security and sharing tab.  I've searched and adding the following MSBuild arguments still doesn't seem to work:

**/m:1 /p:UseWPP_CopyWebApplication=true /p:PipelineDependsOnBuild=false /p:BuildInParallel=false /p:DeployOnBuild=true**

I also have a wpp.target file and this seems to be what is failing

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <UsingTask TaskName="TransformXml"
             AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.dll"/>

  <!-- Make sure web.config will be there even for package/publish -->
  <!--Target Name="CopyWebConfig" BeforeTargets="Build;Rebuild;ConfigTransform">
    <Message Text="Replacing web.config with base." Importance="high" />
    <Copy SourceFiles="Web.base.config"
          DestinationFiles="Web.config"
          OverwriteReadOnlyFiles="true"
          SkipUnchangedFiles="false" />
  </Target-->

  <Target Name="ConfigTransform" BeforeTargets="Build;Rebuild" Condition="Exists('Web.$(Configuration).config')">
    <Message Text="Transforming: Web.$(Configuration).config" Importance="high" />
    <!--TransformXml Source="Web.Base.config"
                  Transform="Web.$(Configuration).config"
                  StackTrace="True"
                  Destination="Web.config" /-->
  </Target>
</Project>
```

The error is below and I'm fresh out of ideas...

> C:\Builds***.wpp.targets (17): Exception: Could not write Destination file: Access to the path 'C:\Builds***Web.config' is denied.
>      at Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.TransformXml.SaveTransformedFile(XmlTransformableDocument document, String destinationFile)
>      at Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.TransformXml.Execute()
>   UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\Builds**Web.config' is denied.
>      at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
>      at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
>      at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
>      at System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor(String path, Boolean append, Encoding encoding, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean checkHost)
>      at System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor(String path, Boolean append, Encoding encoding, Int32 bufferSize)
>      at System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor(String path, Boolean append, Encoding encoding)
>      at Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.XmlAttributePreservingWriter..ctor(String fileName, Encoding encoding)

Comment: Is that path longer than 255 characters?  Also, you need to make very sure that the build is actually being executed with the tfsbuild user and that the user has **Full** access (no limitations) to the `c:\builds`.

Comment: I don't think so.  The path is below. I've removed some sensitive info. C:\Builds\2\*****\EPS Continuous Integration\src\***.*****\***.****\Web.config' is denied.

Comment: I have given the TFSBuild user full access to the share and the build folder  How can i see if it is actually being executed by the TFSBuild user.

Comment: Is it executing on the same machine as the file system?  Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12905693/tfs-2012-build-access-to-path-denied

Comment: Yes the build folder is on the same machine as the build service.  I checked out the link and it seems pretty confusing.  I added the /p:BuildInParallel=false that was suggested in one of the comments

Comment: When I commented out the line in the wpp.target it started working.  So i guess the real question is how do i get the web.config transform to work.

Comment: Have you looked at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16311981/tfs-2012-and-web-config-transforms